# How to measure overlap of groups in pandas groupby objects?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe that looks like

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({"class": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"], "id": [1,2,3,4,5,6], "value": [100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 103]})

example_df
  class  id  value
0     A   1    100
1     A   2    100
2     A   3    101
3     B   4    101
4     B   5    102
5     B   6    103
```

I would like to know, for each `class` A or B, how unique its `value`s are; that is, how many values it shares with the other class. (You can assume that there are only two classes.) For example, given the dataframe above, A shares one value with `B`.

It's not hard to do this by breaking out the columns into `set`s and computing the intersections manually, but that's not very nice. Is there an elegant way to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I think set calculation is OK, you can use `numpy.intersect1d()`:

```
import numpy as np
g = example_df.groupby("class")
a = g.get_group("A")
b = g.get_group("B")
np.intersect1d(a.value, b.value)
```

here is an other method that `groupby` value, this looks good, but I think it slower than the 
`intersect1d` version:

```
(example_df.groupby("value")["class"].nunique() > 1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do query like this:

```
>>> example_df[['class', 'value']].drop_duplicates().groupby('value').size()
value
100      1
101      2
102      1
103      1
```

You can then check all records with `2`. I could be more specific if you give desired output.